# Rails 4: Validating attribute uniqueness of has many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a fridge and I want to be able to place products in the fridge. Sounds OK, but there are two rules:

1. There is only capacity for only 1 of each product in the fridge.
2. There is a defined of set of products that I can put in the fridge. The max capacity in the fridge is:

   - 1 Cheese
   - 1 Egg
   - 1 Milk
   - 1 Butter
   - 1 Bell Pepper
   - 1 Lettuce

The models look like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :fridge 
   # Type product
   enum type: [:cheese, :egg, :milk, :butter, :bell_pepper, :lettuce]
end

class Fridge < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
end
```

Is it possible to set up a validator in the fridge model in order to satisfy the defined rules?

Comment: Yes. Just read the guide about custom validation. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

app/validators/my_validator.rb

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    types = record.fridge.products.select(:type).map &:type
    type = record.type
    if types.include? type
      record.errors[:name] << 'Only 1 capacity for each product'
    end
  end
end
```

Then include your custom validator in your app/models/product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with MyValidator
  belongs_to :fridge

end
```

Also remember to add this to your config/application.rb in order to load the path:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W["#{config.root}/app/validators/"]
```